# warning: mail() [function mail]: SMTP server response: 550.5.7.1 <email@gmail.com>... Relaying denied. IP name possibly forged [191...174] in line 100

Tags: php, phpmailer

Actualmente tengo una aplicación que envía correos a través de **phpmailer**.

El problema es que solo envía correos que tienen el dominio de mi empresa.

cuando existe un correo que es dominio **gmail**, **hotmail** u otro dominio, no envía y muestra el siguiente mensaje:

```
 warning: mail() [function mail]: SMTP server response: 550.5.7.1 <email@gmail.com>... Relaying denied. IP name possibly forged [191...] in line 100
```

mi linea 100 contiene:

```
 mail($destinatario,$asunto,$body);
```

El los datos que utilizo de **smtp** es un correo de mi empresa.

pienso que es una configuración se seguridad que no tengo, alguien me podrá ayudar?

```
   $sql = "select EMAIL1_CLI from planilla";      

                $rpt = mysqli_query($sub_db,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
                //$asunto = 'Aviso de Deuda'; 

                $mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
                $body             = "Este es un mensaje automatico...";


                $mail->From       = "no-responder@xx.cl";
                $mail->FromName   = "Francisco Acevedo Diaz";



                $mail->AddAddress('francisco@gmail.com','Clientes'); //deb poner variable que traiga mail y nombre del cliente
                $mail->SetFrom('cobranza@xx.cl', 'Depto. Cobranza');



                $asunto = $mail->Subject = 'Aviso de deuda en oriental Motors';


                $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
                $mail->MsgHTML($body);



                $mail->IsSMTP();
                $mail->Host = "mail.xx.cl";


                // optional
                // used only when SMTP requires authentication  
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Username = 'xx';
                $mail->Password = 'xx';


                while ($des = mysqli_fetch_array($rpt)) {
                    $destinatario = $des["EMAIL1_CLI"];
                    printf ($destinatario);

                    //$mail->AddAddress = $des['EMAIL1_CLI'];
                    //$mail->AddAddress("facevedo@xx.cl");
                    mail($destinatario,$asunto,$body);

                }   

                    if(!$mail->Send()) {
                      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                      exit;
                    } else {
                      echo "Message sent!";
                    }
                }
```

**edicion 2 (envia los correos a todos, pero envia como 5 correos a cada destinataro):**

```
   $sql = "select EMAIL1_CLI from planilla";      

                $rpt = mysqli_query($sub_db,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());


                $mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
                $body             = "Este es un mensaje automatico...";


                $mail->From       = "no-responder@xx.cl";
                $mail->FromName   = "Francisco Acevedo";




                $mail->SetFrom('cobranza@xx.cl', 'Depto. Cobranza');



                $asunto = $mail->Subject = 'Aviso de deuda en oriental Motors';


                $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
                $mail->MsgHTML($body);



                $mail->IsSMTP();
                $mail->Host = "mail.xx.cl";



                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Username = 'xx';
                $mail->Password = 'xx';


                while ($des = mysqli_fetch_array($rpt)) {
                    $destinatario = $des["EMAIL1_CLI"];

                    $mail->AddAddress($destinatario);

                    $mail->send();

                }
```

Comment: Deberías mostrar algo más de código donde configuras phpmailer. Y una pregunta, si estas usando phpmailer, ¿por que usas la función mail de php?

Comment: @asantanao adjunte el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente logre encontrar la solución, tenia 2 problemas:

1) El primero: Estaba ocupando 2 metodos a la misma vez, uno el propio tal de php *(function mail)*,
 y a la misma vez la librería de *phpmailer*, fue por eso que tenia conflictos con las cantidades de correos recibidos y enviados...

2) El segundo: tenia problemas de sintaxis en la lineas de códigos al utilizar el metodo ***While***.

Finalmente la solución fue re-configurar *phpmailer* y desabilitar *(function mail)*

**De este modo la sintaxis correcta fue la siguiente:**

```
            $mail = new PHPMailer();

            // Activamos el servicio SMTP
            $mail->isSMTP();
            // Activamos / Desactivamos el "debug" de SMTP 
            // 0 = Apagado 
            // 1 = Mensaje de Cliente 
            // 2 = Mensaje de Cliente y Servidor 
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 

            // Log del debug SMTP en formato HTML 
            $mail->Debugoutput = 'html'; 

            // Servidor SMTP (para este ejemplo utilizamos gmail) 
            $mail->Host = 'mail.xx.com'; 

            // Puerto SMTP 
            $mail->Port = 587; 

            // Tipo de encriptacion SSL ya no se utiliza se recomienda TSL 
            $mail->SMTPSecure = ''; 

            // Si necesitamos autentificarnos 
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 

            // Usuario del correo desde el cual queremos enviar, para Gmail recordar usar el usuario completo (usuario@gmail.com) 
            $mail->Username = "xx"; 

            // Contraseña 
            $mail->Password = "xx"; 

            // Conectamos a la base de datos 
            //$db = new mysqli('hostname', 'usuario', 'cotraseña', 'basededatos'); 

            if ($sub_db->connect_errno > 0) { 
                die('Imposible conectar [' . $sub_db->connect_error . ']'); 
            } 

            // Creamos la sentencias SQL 
            $result = $sub_db->query("SELECT * FROM planilla");

            // Iniciamos el "bucle" para enviar multiples correos. 

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                //Añadimos la direccion de quien envia el corre, primero el correo, luego el nombre de quien lo envia. 


                $mail->setFrom('xx@xx.cl', 'Depto. Cobranza'); 
                $mail->addAddress($row['EMAIL'], $row['NOMBRE']); 

                //La linea de asunto 
                $mail->Subject = 'Aviso de Deuda!'; 

                // La mejor forma de enviar un correo, es creando un HTML e insertandolo de la siguiente forma, PHPMailer permite insertar, imagenes, css, etc. (No se recomienda el uso de Javascript) 
                $body = "Estimado cliente ";
                $mail->MsgHTML($body);

                // Enviamos el Mensaje 
                $mail->send(); 

                // Borramos el destinatario, de esta forma nuestros clientes no ven los correos de las otras personas y parece que fuera un único correo para ellos. 
                $mail->ClearAddresses(); 
            }
```

Muchas Gracias a quienes apoyaron en las respuestas .

Answer (score 1):

Estas utilizando la función mail, que es interna de php, en la sentencia

```
mail($destinatario,$asunto,$body)
```

con lo que no estas usando phpmailer para hacer el envio. En phpmailer se envia  con la funcion send(). Para enviar con PHPMailer deberías utilizar;

```
$mail->send();
```

Puedes revisar la documentación en [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
Además tiene un ejemplo simple de como enviar mensajes con PHPMailer.

Comment: la solucion seria  `$mail->send($destinatario,$asunto,$body);`  ?

Comment: No, sería simplemente $mail->send(); $mail no es otra cosa que un objeto de tipo PHPMailer, y a medida que lo vas configurando con las diferentes funciones guarda la configuracion. Hecha un vistazo al ejemplo del enlace que te he dejado

Comment: ya lo probe, y no llegan los correos, necesitas que te adjunte alguna otra liinea del phpmailer?

Comment: luego si hago esto: `$mail->AddAddress = $des['EMAIL1_CLI'];`  me indica que debo proporcionar al menos un correo electronico.. me podras ayudar?

Comment: realice una edición, pero ahora envía como 5 correos a cada destinatario, siendo que debiera ser solo 1

Comment: Puede ser qe los 5 correos se hayan acumulado despues de varias peticiones, no que se haya enviado en uno solo. En principio con el codigo que tienes deberia funcionar.  Lo que podrias tambien es usar un try...catch como el ejemplo qe esta en github, para controlar si no se envia

Answer (score 0):

El error en sí está relacionado con que un servidor SMTP no te está reconociendo como un usuario autorizado para enviar mails a través de éste. Esta es una protección anti-spam. Algunos servidores, como GMail, tienen restricciones bastantes altas para evitar ésto. Éste permiso usualmente está basado en direcciones IP permitidas o en un login usuario/contraseña.

Algunos cosas para tener en cuenta :
1) Del punto de vista del servidor, por ejemplo; verificar la dirección DNS inversa, verificar que la dirección IP no esté en alguna lista negra, etc.
2) Del punto de vista del código: completar el campo del destinantario con el nombre además de la dirección de mail, agregar un campo "Responder A" (y que sea válido), etc.

*NOTA: Respecto al segundo punto veo que usás "From" y "SetFrom" a la vez y diferentes y que no definiste un campo "addReplyTo".*

Espero que ésto sirva de ayuda, saludos!

Comment: gracias, me gustaria que me ayudaras a editar mi código en base a lo que dices... soy novato en esto de php

Comment: ingrese una edicion 2 en mi pregunta..

Comment: lo hice, manda 2 correos a cada usuario... porque 2? estara configurado en otra parte? tengo en el php.ini y en el phpmailer

Comment: en la base tengo 2 correos distintos, y envia 2 correos a cada uno, el correo si  se puede repetir en otra dato... pero ahora en este caso debiera mandar solo 1 debido a que no esta repetido el correo en otro dato

Comment: repeti el mismo email 3 veces en la base, para ver si enviaba 3 correos, y sigue enviando 2. que sera?

Comment: cada dato en la base guarda el email del cliente y otros detalles..
el email se puede repetir, pero con distintos detalles.
la idea es que el programa recorra el campo de email y envie el detalle al cliente, independiente si el email se repite, pero el detalle es dintinto.

Comment: Para no seguir extendiendo ésto y que sea de utilidad: 1) chequear que  la consulta devuelva solamente una dirección por fila 2) si fuera así, el echo debería mostrar solamente una dirección por cada ciclo del while 3) si el echo muestra solamente un destinatario, tal vez AddAdress esté acumulando datos, probar con mail->clearAddresses(); después de cada envío. Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83223/discussion-between-francisco-acevedo-and-l-alejandro-m).